# How can I make GitLab SAST scanner mark a vulnerability as a false positive?

Tags: gitlab

According to [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/#false-positive-detection):

> GitLab SAST can identify certain types of false positive results in
> the output of other tools. These results are flagged as false
> positives on the Vulnerability Report and the Vulnerability Page.
>
> False positive detection is available in a subset of the supported
> languages and analyzers:
>
> - Go, in the Semgrep-based analyzer
> - Ruby, in the Brakeman-based analyzer

I am using [internal GitLab Semgrep analyzer](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/semgrep) for GO which is based on [Semgrep analyzer](https://github.com/returntocorp/semgrep).

There is no information in the docs how to mark a vulnerability as a false positive via internal analyzer and there is no such information for [sast-rules](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/sast-rules), which are used by this analyzer. Also I can't find any information in the Semgrep documentation that it is possible to mark vulnerability as a false positive, only how to [ignore](https://semgrep.dev/docs/ignoring-files-folders-code/#reference-summary) it.

My question is: what do I need to do to get the GitLab SAST scanner to mark the vulnerability as a false positive?